# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Json parsing in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

code:

```
var json:NSString;
json = NSString(format:"{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]")
var data:NSData = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var dataDic:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil) as! NSDictionary
```

I formed my own json and when i try yo parse it give error as "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".I assume that the cause of issue is passing empty json for pasing.I do not know how to solve this problem?.thanks in advance

Comment: This fails because your JSON is invalid. Hint: check for matching parentheses (or check on http://jsonlint.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let jsonString = "{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]}"
if let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    var error: NSError?
    if let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let dictionaries = jsonDict["und"] as? [AnyObject] {
            for dictionary in dictionaries {
                if let value = dictionary["value"] as? String {
                    println(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Martin R suggested The problem is in your `json` String. so just modify it like this:

```
"{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]}"
```

You forgot to add `}` at last.

Without `}` it can not be cast as `NSDictionary` thats why it become `nil` at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare a variable uninitialized as you did. Replace

```
var json:NSString
```

to

```
var json:NSString!
```

The exclamation declaration will automatically unwrap the optional value where it is used (so you do not need to write `json!`) but you need to ensure that it is initialized somehow.